# How can I create a custom variable attribute to direct movs into different address spaces?

Tags: gcc

So, I'm building a custom backend for GCC for a processor. This processor has 4 address spaces: local, global, mmm, and mmr. I want to make it such that when writing c code, you can do this:

```
int global x = 5;
```

which would cause the compiler to spit out an instruction like this:

```
ldi.g %reg, 5
```

I know that certain processors like blackfin and MeP do something similar to this, so I figure its possible to do, however I have no idea how to do it. The technique that should allow me to do this is a [variable attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes).

Any suggestions on how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add target-specific attributes by registering a `struct attribute_spec` table using `TARGET_ATTRIBUTE_TABLE`, as described in the [GCC internals documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gccint/Target-Attributes.html#Target-Attributes).  The details of `struct attribute_spec` can be found in the source (`gcc/tree.h`).

This handler doesn't *need* to do anything beyond returning `NULL_TREE`, although typically it will at least do some error checking.  (Read the comments in `gcc/tree.h`, and look at examples in other targets.)

Later, you can obtain the list of attributes for a declaration tree node with `DECL_ATTRIBUTES()` (see [the internals docs again](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gccint/Attributes.html#Attributes)), and use `lookup_attribute()` (see `gcc/tree.h` again) to see if a given attribute in the list.

You want to references to a symbol to generate different assembly based on your new attributes, so you probably want to use the `TARGET_ENCODE_SECTION_INFO` hook [("Define this hook if references to a symbol or a constant must be treated differently depending on something about the variable or function named by the symbol")](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gccint/Sections.html#Sections) to set a flag on the `symbol_ref` (as the docs suggest).  You can [define a predicate](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gccint/Defining-Predicates.html#Defining-Predicates) for testing this flag in the .md .

Comment: Thank you for the advice. So,

I created my attribute table inside the target.c file and linked it with the TARGET_ATTRIBUTE_TABLE macro. Then I have a function inside the attribute table that is supposed to handle each attribute. Should I assess if a given attribute is in the list then? Finally, how can I use that function call to then redirect the movsi rtx in my target.md file? What information gets passed to the .md part that will allow it to choose between the different address spaces?

Comment: Updated - you're asking for more details than I thought you were.